# Pass string with special character to grep as pattern

Tags: 14.04, grep

Trying to filter command output according pattern -p

```
docker run --help |grep -F '-p'
```

But grep treats it as -p as command option:

```
grep: invalid option -- 'p'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

How to make grep search according `-p` pattern?

Comment: `grep -F -- '-p'` or `grep -F -e '-p'`

Comment: I'm reading `grep --help` and still can't understand meaning of `--` in `grep -F -- '-p'`. And also can't understand `-e` in `grep -F -e '-p'`.  I suppose `-e` is `--regexp=PATTERNS` ? But how it helps there? Why not enough `-F`?